# What does the "example.com" refer to in a GET request?

Tags: html, http, get, f5

What does the "example.com" refer to in the GET request such as this F5 health monitor example:

```
GET /somefolder HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n

GET / [uri path]
HTTP/1.1 [http encoding]
[Carriage Return/LineFeed]
Host: [required for http 1.1 to specify the next part]
www.example.com  <**?????**>
Connection: Close [command to end query request]
[CR/LF/CR/LF]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it's saying which domain the request is intended for. You're asking for path `/` but a single server could be serving hundreds of domains, so it needs to know *which* `/` you want.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this as I deal with much more complex issues within networks.  But it is still confusing me.  What if the webserver is NOT publicly accessible, or let's say there is no DNS server available to resolve the host?  What if the host name is wrong?  I don't understand what it is calling for "within" the get request.  It has a path, that leads to an object at the end of the URI....but what does the host matter to anything?  What is the requirement for success or failure of the actual GET request?  Do you see what I am saying?

Comment: Also, it's the begnning of the GET where the first / is that determines the path on the server you are requesting it on.  The host field does NOT change that you are asking for the GET on a destination already.  Even if it is serving hundreds of domains...a "/" without and url in the beginning means the GET is only checking the path AFTER "any" url on that webserver.  I know this because we do it all the time on our F5 load balancers for health checks.

Comment: You seem to be equating `www.example.com` to a specific host (i.e. physical machine) - that is not the case here. All the DNS has already happened - the client has found the correct physical server for it's request. But that server may handle not just `www.example.com` (in `/var/example.com/html`) but also `www.mysite.com` (in `/var/mysite.com/html`). If all it had was `/` it would not know which file to serve. With the addition of the host header, it does. The server isn't resolving `www.example.com` with DNS, it's using it as a lookup into it's own configuration.

Comment: So.  You are saying that the host is a path on the server itself?  Part of it's path lookup (internally) to find out which website it is hosting the URI on, if it has more than one website?  

If this is correct I am marking you as the right answer.  Please confirm.

Comment: Correct. To be a little more specific, it's a reference into the web server's configuration, which in turn would (in simple cases) map to a file path. In more complex setups the configuration may not be a simple path, but it still holds that the host header is the key which tells the server which config entires to use. There's a nice example in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: I tested this out on a server hosting only one site and when I changed it to nonsense, nothing broke the health check (Get string functionality).  So, it seems true that if the server only hosts one website therefore making only one path URI available for the GET request, the host field won't make any difference.

My rep is too low to even vote this up...but I selected you as the right answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> `www.example.com` is the hostname.

The intent of the Host header mechanism, and in particular the requirement that enforces its presence in HTTP/1.1 requests, is to speed the transition away from assigning a new IP address for every vanity URL.

Refer: [Key Differences between HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html)

Comment: I don't use SO very often, so rather than repeat my clarification, please see my comment under the first reply above.  I am still not understanding the implication of a proper or improper host field, and how it affects the GET.